# PHP inserting variable into a link href and name

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the code I am working with:

```
<?php
    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('http://hugeriver.wordpress.com/feed/');
    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $item = array ( 
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('encoded')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            );
        array_push($feed, $item);
    }
    $limit = count($feed);
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
        $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
        $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
        echo '<h2><a name="test">'.$title.'</a><span class="line"></span></h2>';
        echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
        echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
    }
?>
```

I am stuck specifically with this line. I am trying to make it so the title is both the name of the ancor and the link (so when clicked it scrolls to the top). This is what I tried that doesn't work. Can anyone please show me what is wrong with my syntax?

```
echo '<h2><a name="'.$title'" href="#'.$title'">'.$title.'</a><span class="line"></span></h2>';
```

Comment: Is the missing dot on your 2 code block a typo ? I will assume it is since you have the dot right on your main code block `"'.$title.'"` and `"'.$title'"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
echo '<h2><a name="'.$title.'" href="#'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a><span class="line"></span></h2>';
```

You are missing dots after $title

Also, your links link to themself. You need to define a seperate anchor and then link to it.

Comment: `echo` with `.` means pointless concatenation. `echo` accepts `,`. So don't `echo 'why'.'concatenate'.'this';` but do `echo 'when', 'echo', 'does', 'it', 'for', 'you';`.

Answer (score 3):

You're currently creating a link that targets itself.

If you want the link to go to the top of the document when clicked, simply link to `'#'`:

```
<a href="#" name="<?php echo $title ?>"><?php echo $title ?></a>
```

Also, [`name` is deprecated on `<a/>` elements in HTML 5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a). Use `id` instead:

```
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $title ?>"><?php echo $title ?></a>
```

Comment: I want the link to go to the title when clicked. So instead of ahref = # I would like ahref = $title please

Comment: You want the link to go to itself? `<a href="#<?php echo $title ?>" id="<?php echo $title ?>"><?php echo $title ?></a>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" ID="<?php echo htmlentities($title, ENT_QUOTES); ?>">
    <?php echo htmlentities($title, ENT_NOQUOTES); ?></a>
```

**Why is everyone forgetting `htmlentities()`, especially for attributes?**

And why use `$title` as `#target`? When the `$title` is a variable with spaces and punctuation unfit for `#target` practice... Why not use an `md5($title)` since your generating the page dynamically? Like:

```
<a href="#" ID="<?php echo htmlentities(md5($title), ENT_QUOTES); ?>">
    <?php echo htmlentities($title, ENT_NOQUOTES); ?></a>
```

and later on linking to it like this:

```
<a href="#<?php echo htmlentities(md5($title), ENT_QUOTES); ?>">
    Go to <?php echo htmlentities($title, ENT_NOQUOTES); ?>!</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Andre answer should solve your problem, if what you want to do is simply go to the top of the page. however if you want to go to a specific section that has id set to the value of $title then you can try this...

```
<a href="#<?php echo $title ?>" name="<?php echo $title ?>"><?php echo $title ?></a>
```

This way when the link is clicked it will jump to the exact element with ID equal to title(which may or may not be at the top). I believe this is what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

there are two missing dots.

try this:

```
echo '<h2><a name="'.$title.'" href="#'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a><span class="line"></span></h2>';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this syntax

```
echo "<h2><a name=\"$title\" href=\"#$title\">$title</a><span class=\"line\"></span></h2>";
```

or

```
echo "<h2><a name='$title' href='#$title'>$title</a><span class='line'></span></h2>";
```

This is much cleaner and has less probability of missing a dot or closing/opening quote.